# Android API Google Drive "connection failed"

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I try to work with the API Google Drive on Android, first using the demo:

https://github.com/googledrive/android-quickstart

However, I have this error that I can not solve .

> GoogleApiClient connection failed:
>   ConnectionResult{statusCode=SIGN_IN_REQUIRED,
>   resolution=PendingIntent{421d40e8: android.os.BinderProxy@42137f78}}

```
@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
    // Called whenever the API client fails to connect.
    Log.i(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connection failed: " + result.toString());
    if (!result.hasResolution()) {
        // show the localized error dialog.
        GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(result.getErrorCode(), this, 0).show();
        return;
    }
    // The failure has a resolution. Resolve it.
    // Called typically when the app is not yet authorized, and an
    // authorization
    // dialog is displayed to the user.
    try {
        result.startResolutionForResult(this, REQUEST_CODE_RESOLUTION);
    } catch (SendIntentException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception while starting resolution activity", e);
        // There was an error with the resolution intent. Try again.
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_RESOLUTION) {

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Error resolution success.");

            // Make sure the app is not already connected or attempting to connect
            if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting() &&
                    !mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }

        } else {
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(requestCode, this, 0).show();
        }

        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: In my case, this error was caused by something of the app package not matching that in the credential.  One needs to make sure the package name and SHA1 must match.  The debug version running on a dev machine may have different package name and SHA1 from that of the release version.

Answer (score 3):

This may be due to negligence on developer's part (as it happened with me) - the SHA1 details you provide on the console are that of production key and you are testing on Debug mode (the SHA1 details would be different). The error message google drive API, gives could have been better, though!

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/ConnectionResult.html#SIGN_IN_REQUIRED) is the info for the error you are receiving. I assume you are, but you need to be signed in to access Drive. When I run the sample app, at the very beginning it asks me to choose an account. Perhaps you do not have an account synced with the device you are using? There is an option to "add account", but maybe the behaviour is different when you have zero accounts. The documentation suggests that you either continue without using the API (simply because you cannot unless you sign in) or call `startResolutionForResult(Activity, int)` to prompt the user to sign in, but it would probably be easiest to just [add the account to your device](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/2521798?hl=en).

Comment: Strange, without changing anything in my code it works on my Sony tablet but not on the Samsung O.o

Comment: Are you signed into both devices with the same account?

Comment: Yes with the same account

Comment: It works on my Samsung tablet after have formatted it.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/41658044/4448757 to connect with google account, this works perfectly only in signed apk

then after you can go for google drive

```
   IntentSender intentSender = Drive.DriveApi
            .newOpenFileActivityBuilder()
            .build(mGoogleApiClient);
    try {
        startIntentSenderForResult(intentSender, DRIVE_CHOOSER_REQUEST, null, 0, 0, 0);
    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if somebody still needs this, but in my case I had two google accounts so I first need to choose which account I want to use. I used this code in the `onConnectionFailed`

```
    if (!connectionResult.hasResolution())
    {
        // show the localized error dialog.
        GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(connectionResult.getErrorCode(), mContext, 0).show();
        return;
    }

    try
    {
        connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(mContext, 1);
    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```