# Google Android Drive api sign in fails on installed version

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-api-client

I have developed an android application that uses the GoogleDrive api,

When under debug or running the debug version, the application 
works fine, and correctly authenticates to the attached google account..etc.
When I build a release version, (with my signed keys), and 
install the apk file, when I run, 
the Googleapiclient fails to "connect",  using the same 
google account that works under debug, 
giving me a "Sign in Failed" message, after it tries once to resolve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

solution was here https://developers.google.com/drive/android/get-started

I need to create a seperate OAuth 2.0 client ID for the 
released version of my application,  using the sha1 key
from my release key.

Comment: This helped me. I had set up my key correctly but the package name had some different capitalisation. After I changed it to be consistent, it was happy days!

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to start one intent to get the login credential

```
    if(mGoogleApiClient == null){
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(Drive.API)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .enableAutoManage(this, this)
                .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
                .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(AppIndex.API)
        .build();
    }
    Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, DRIVE_SIGNIN_RESULT);
```

No need to connect the mGoogleApiClient here
you can create GoogleSignInResult object from the intent data you have received in onActivityResult

```
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case DRIVE_SIGNIN_RESULT:
                GoogleSignInResult signInResult = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
                handleSignInResult(signInResult);
                break;
        }
    }
```

Connect mGoogleApiClient now

```
    private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();
            mGoogleApiClient.connect(GoogleApiClient.SIGN_IN_MODE_OPTIONAL);
        }
    }
```